# C Loan Calculator returns all 0.00

Tags: c

Everything just comes back as 0.00, can anyone see why it may do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MONTHS 12

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    double p, r, y, rate, months;
    double old_balance, interest, principal, payment, new_balance;
    long real_payment;


    printf("This program calculates your bank loan repayment plan\n");
    printf("Please enter the principal (q to quit)\n");
    while (scanf("%f", &p) ==1)
    {
        if (p <= 0.00)
            printf("Invalid Entry\n");
        break;
    }

    printf("please enter the annual interest rate (q to quit)\n");
    while (scanf("%f", &r) ==1)
    {
        if (r > 0.00)   
            rate = r/100.00;
        else
            printf("Invalid Entry\n");
        break;
    }

    printf("Please enter the duration of the loan in years (q to quit)\n");
    while (scanf("%f", &y) ==1)
    {
        if (y > 0.00)   
            months = y*12.00;
        else
            printf("Invalid Entry\n");
        break;
    }

    payment = (p*rate)/(1.00-(pow((1.00+rate),-months)));
    old_balance = p;
    interest = old_balance*months;
    principal = payment-interest;
    new_balance = old_balance-principal;
    real_payment = ((payment*100.00) + 0.5)/100.0;

    printf("%f  %f\n", rate, months);
    printf("Month             Old Balance              Payment                  Interest                 Principal            New Balance\n");
    for (i = 0; i < MONTHS; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d   %20.2f     %20.2f     %20.2f     %20.2f %20.2f\n", i+1, old_balance, real_payment, interest, principal, new_balance);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please feel free to ask any questions, new to C, just learning. Thanks for help in advance. :)

Comment: `scanf("%f", &p)` : use `"%lf"` instead of `"%f"` for `double`.

Comment: This is not C++. This is C.

Comment: No dice, but thank you.

Comment: It seems like you are printing out the same data over and over inside the loop..

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the original code was valid C++

Comment: @Code_Spent could you please clarify whether you are using a C compiler or a C++ compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `scanf("%f",...)` to `scanf("%lf",...)` solves the issue for me. The data values in the table are no longer output as zeros. Since the `scanf` function is looking for a float in your code, it doesn't correctly read the data from the user, hence the zeros.